# Proof of $cos(Ht) = \sum_\sigma cos(\sigma) \left | w_\sigma \right > \left < v_\sigma \right |$ in Quantum Singular Value Transform

Tags: simulation, hamiltonian-simulation, hamiltonian

I am reading the [grand unification of quantum algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.02859), and read over the hamiltonian simulation technique.

However, I am a bit confused. They pose that

$
e^{-iHt} = cos(Ht) - isin(Ht)
$

for all square matrices, $H$.

Then they use this fact to reduce the problem of hamiltonian simulation to finding $cos(Ht)$ and $sin(Ht)$, which is all well and good.

Then they make approximations for $cos(xt)$ and $-isin(xt)$ using Bessel functions. These functions will get applied to the singular values of $H$.

My question is this:
It was proven that $e^{-iHt} = cos(Ht) - isin(Ht)$, but it was never proven that $cos(Ht) = \sum_\sigma cos(\sigma t) \left | w_\sigma \right > \left < v_\sigma \right |$ (and the same for $-isin(xt)$, where $\sigma$ denotes the singular values of $H$, $w_\sigma$ denotes a left singular vector, and $v_\sigma$ denotes a right singular vector.

Wouldn't a proof of this be necessary to assert that quantum simulation can be done by simply using QSVT on the singular values?

I also wrote a simple python script to demonstrate that this is not the case:

```
import numpy as np
import math as math
import pandas as pd

#cosine taylor series
def cos(x):
    f = x - x

    for i in range(30): #finite cutoff of 30
        f = f + ((-1) ** i) * (np.power(x, 2 * i)) * 1 / math.factorial(2 * i)
    
    return f

#example hermitian matrix
G = np.array([
    [3, 1, 2, 3],
    [1, 9, 4, 2],
    [2, 4, 5, 1],
    [3, 2, 1, 7]
])

svd = np.linalg.svd(G)

mat = [[0] * len(G)] * len(G)

for i in range(len(svd[1])):
    mat += cos(svd[1][i]) * np.outer(np.transpose(svd[0])[i], svd[2][i])

print(pd.DataFrame(cos(G))) #cosine of the matrix
print(pd.DataFrame(mat)) #cosine of the singular values (reconstruct the matrix)
```

Comment: If $H$ is Hermitian then the singular value decomposition is the same as the eigenvalue decomposition but you take the absolute value of the eigenvalues. But for normal matrices you apply functions to them via the eigenvalue decomposition and not the SVD. This will be why you aren't getting the correct result.

Comment: Looking at the paper they even write this: "However, note that the above relation only holds if the eigenvalues of H are positive, such that the singular values are equal to the eigenvalues."

Comment: @Rammus I tried the eigenvalue decomposition too. I replaced `svd = np.linalg.svd(G)` with `eig = np.linalg.eig(G)`. Then I performed my `cos` function on every eigenvalue and multiplied that by the outer product of the eigenvectors. This also did not yield the correct result.

Comment: All the eigenvalues are positive according to a `print(eig)`, but the eigenvectors contain negative entries. I don't think eigenvectors' sign matters though.

Comment: But what are you comparing it to? What is `cos(G)` computing? Is it an elementwise function?

Comment: @Rammus `cos(G)` implements the taylor series of $cos(x)$. I wrote the implementation at the top of my code. The code I wrote works for matrix inputs because I am using numpy to calculate matrix powers and matrix sums.

Comment: Nevermind, it was an issue with my cosine taylor series function. I think I was experiencing floating point errors. I used scipy's existing function and got the correct result. Thank you very much for your help.